# "A Java Exception has occured" what might be the cause?

Tags: java, exception, jar, runtime-error, execution

When my jar is run on another computer there occurs a java exception but on my setup it runs ok. They are using Java 1.8? atleast one of them is. and my JDK is also 1.8.

Could the cause of this be in META-INF?  I also tried sending .class files and running the main class using cmd (it maybe gave some other error i think)

Also I've exported it as a jar from eclipse, not executable jar. Could this be the cause?

**EDIT**
One of the stacktraces says: "*Unsupported major.minor version 52.0*‏"

Comment: Post the exception stack trace.

Comment: ask them to run it by opening a command line window and execute `java -jar thejar.jar`, and to paste the stack trace they get. It contains the cause.

Comment: okay, there's one stacktraces now :) or well.. not the whole stack trace I quess? but signs of something causing the error :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java version mismatch. The other computer not really running with JRE 8. 
See this answer for detail [Unsupported major.minor version 52.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489398/unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0)

Answer (score 1):

Your code was compiled with Java Version 1.8 while it is being executed with Java Version 1.7 or below.