# JHipster + mvn spring-boot:run

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, jhipster

When I run `mvn spring-boot:run -log`, this error appears https://goo.gl/xQS5vY (I put in the Google Drive, because the number of characters exceeded the limits).

Somebody can help me?

Thanks.

@Edited
The log is in four different files, I do not know what part I put in the post, but the link is from google drive where they are only 4 txt files (https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BwijxlJDuqYBfjRFY0t3Q2NuR1IzbVRHWmVjaHhoMGwxZDVvQXNhcjdmUzdDbjR2VGVFVEk&usp=sharing). Here is a part of the error

---

```
Test set: test6.service.UserServiceTest

Tests run: 6, Failures: 0, Errors: 6, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 5.407 sec 
<<< FAILURE! - in test6.service.UserServiceTest assertThatOnlyActivatedUserCanRequestPasswordReset(test6.service.UserServiceTest) Time elapsed: 0.001 sec <<< ERROR! java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext at
    org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:94) at
    org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:72) at
    org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117) at
    org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83) at
    org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:212) at
    org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:200) at
    ... (snipped some lines)
    org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153) at
    org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103) 
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/t.taraczuk/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-swagger2/2.0.3/springfox-swagger2-2.0.3.jar!/springfox/documentation/swagger2/mappers/LicenseMapper$License.class]; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/mapstruct/Qualifier : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 at
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:303) at
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:248) at
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanAnnotationParser.parse(ComponentScanAnnotationParser.java:140) at
    (... snipped some lines)
    org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:264) at
    org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153) at
    org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:124) at
    org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:200) at
    org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153) at
    org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103) 
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/mapstruct/Qualifier : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 at
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) at
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800) at
    java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) at
    java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449) at
    java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71) at
    java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361) at
    java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355) at
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at
    java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354) at
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425) at
    sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308) at
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
```

Comment: Can you trim the error down to something that does fit within your question? I don't know how many people are going to click on a random unknown link.

Comment: Ok, just updated the post

Comment: In the stack trace I see `Unsupported major.minor version 52.0`. That usually indicates that you are attempting to run jars from a different version of java from the one they were compiled with, and the compiler version is later than the executable version. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489398/unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0

Comment: Thanks! Now my project work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As seen in the comment, but anyway you just need to read the stacktrace: this is because you don't have the right Java version installed.