# Could not find or load main class, when attempting to run java -jar

Tags: java, jar

I'm trying to run my application from a prebuilt `.jar` file that I've copied over to a remote host.

My folder structure looks like:

```
/home/user/mp1/
              --| Agent/
                --| agent.jar
              --| META-INF/
                --| MANIFEST.MF
              --| src/
                --| file1.class
                --| file2.class
                --| file3.class
                --| UX.class
```

My manifest looks like:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: src/
Main-Class: UX
```

- My main class is `/home/user/mp1/src/UX.class`
- The command I'm using is from within `mp1`:  `java -jar Agent/agent.jar`
- The error I get is: `Error: Could not find or load main class UX`

Comment: is `UX.class` in agent.jar?? the `.class` in `src` are odd. Also could you please edit  and post the code of "UX"

Comment: Be sure you have in your UX.class `main` method.

Comment: @RC. - It may be that this was not the case. I included the `src` directory in my artifact configs, and now am getting a different error `Unsupported major.minor version 52.0`

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489398/unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0