# Running Java programs in Notepad++

Tags: java, compilation, console, notepad++

I looked up how to run java programs within the notepad++ using the Nppexec plugin. I use the following script to change to the current directory, compile and run the program:

```
cd $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)
javac $(FILE_NAME)
java $(NAME_PART)
```

The code compiles fine, however I get a number of errors when it tries to run. These were the errors I got when I tried to run a simple Hello World java program:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Hello : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "main" <<< Process finished. (Exit code 1)
```

I do have Java JDK installed on my computer and I can run all programs externally. Can anyone help me fix this?

Comment: You are using an old Java version, see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489398/unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0

Comment: Use force, Luke: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/

Answer (score 1):

From the exception (`Unsupported major.minor version 52.0` )it seems you compiled your code using a version of java and you are trying to execute the java class with a different version.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you compile and run with a different version of JDK/JRE (different versions of javac and java on the script).

on cmd, you might check it with

```
> where java
> where javac
> java -version
> javac -version
```

It is well explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi)