# R- rjava.dll not found on java 64 bit and R 64 bit

Tags: java, r, stanford-nlp

I'm trying to install the package `coreNLP` using `devtools::install_github("statsmaths/coreNLP")` and i keep getting this error suggesting a problem in the Java configuration:

```
 error: unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/Mattia/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/rJava/libs/i386/rJava.dll':
 LoadLibrary failure:  %1 non è un'applicazione di Win32 valida.
```

I thought that maybe my Java installation wasn't 64 bit and ran: `java -d64 -version` and i got:

```
java version "1.8.0_101"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)
```

Then i checked R with `R.version`

```
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32
```

I set the PATH in the environmental variables to:

`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\bin\server`

I cannot understand what i'm doing wrong here.

Comment: not a duplicate but perhaps some information [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34716207/installing-corenlp-in-r) might help you figure out what's going on.

Comment: I saw it earlier but this is for Ubuntu and i'm on Windows 10, also the error code is different but thanks anyway