# Initializing coreNLP in R

Tags: stanford-nlp

My issue is very similar to [Cannot Initialize CoreNLP in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48495923/cannot-initialize-corenlp-in-r), however the answer that is provided doesn't work -- R Studio simply crashes

To be clear, I get this:

```
library(coreNLP)
initCoreNLP()
initCoreNLP()
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Searching for resource: StanfordCoreNLP.properties
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator tokenize
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.TokenizerAnnotator - TokenizerAnnotator: No tokenizer type provided. Defaulting to PTBTokenizer.
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator ssplit
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator pos
Reading POS tagger model from edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/english-left3words/english-left3words-distsim.tagger ... done [1.7 sec].
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator lemma
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator ner
Loading classifier from edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz ... done [1.7 sec].
Loading classifier from edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.muc.7class.distsim.crf.ser.gz ... done [1.0 sec].
Loading classifier from edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.conll.4class.distsim.crf.ser.gz ... done [1.0 sec].
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.time.JollyDayHolidays - Initializing JollyDayHoliday for SUTime from classpath edu/stanford/nlp/models/sutime/jollyday/Holidays_sutime.xml as sutime.binder.1.
Error in rJava::.jnew("edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP", basename(path)) : 
 edu.stanford.nlp.util.ReflectionLoading$ReflectionLoadingException: Error creating edu.stanford.nlp.time.TimeExpressionExtractorImpl
```

Alternatively, if I run (in a new session):

```
dyn.load('/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_162.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib')
library(rJava)
library(coreNLP)
initCoreNLP()
```

it just crashes.

My versions of Java:

```
   Williams-MacBook-Pro-2:~ WilliamLS$ /usr/libexec/java_home -V
Matching Java Virtual Machines (5):
9.0.4, x86_64:  "Java SE 9.0.4" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.4.jdk/Contents/Home
1.8.0_162, x86_64:  "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_162.jdk/Contents/Home
1.8.0_161, x86_64:  "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home
1.6.0_65-b14-468, x86_64:   "Java SE 6" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
1.6.0_65-b14-468, i386: "Java SE 6" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.4.jdk/Contents/Home
```

What would you recommend? I also attempted using the cleanNLP package but when I try initializing the

```
init_clean_nlp
```

command, I get the same error as the one written above. Any recommendations?