# Error in rJava::.jnew("edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP", basename(path))

Tags: java, r, stanford-nlp, rjava

I want to use the "`coreNLP`" library in R software. I am using ubuntu, and the java version is 11.0.4.

I have an error during using the `initCoreNLP()`

> Error in rJava::.jnew("edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP", basename(path)) :

I tried to solve this problem by using the [dyn.load('/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48495923/cannot-initialize-corenlp-in-r)

Then remove rJava and reinstall it again.
However, when I use the `dyn.load` in R, it gives me this error

> ibjvm.dylib: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

when I tried to check that if the file is existed by using the below command

`ls /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home`

it show that the `'jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib'` is not exist

**NOTe::**

**I do not have any problem when I use `library(rJava)`**

**also, I used the `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/server` directory to export it in LD_LIBRARY_PATH because it has the `libjvm.so` file**

what should I do now to solve this problem????

Answer (score 0):

`.dylib` is an extension for macOS shared based libraries. If you are using `Ubuntu` it will be `.so`

So, it looks like you have sort of mixed environment. In fact, this layout

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home
```

seems like macOS one.

Anyway. I suggest starting from the very beginning. Try to:

- configure `Java` in `R` using `sudo R CMD javareconf`
- install `rJava` using `install.packages('rJava')
- make sure your `Java` + `R` env. is running fine. I suggest running simple code before jumping towards something more complex. For example:

http://www.owsiak.org/running-java-code-in-r/

- make sure your `coreNLP` is visible from `R` - e.g. it's `JAR` files are on `CLASSPATH`