# How to fix this error Error Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 in Android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

How the fix the gradle error in Android studio after update preview 3?

[image]

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489398/unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0

Comment: what is your java version?

Comment: java version "1.8.0_65"

Comment: There can be two main reasons to occur this problem.

 1. **Java Version Problem**

Check the compatible java version and update your development environments JDK to same version.

 2. **Gradle Version Problem**

This basically the problem in gradle version. Please check project gradle version is equal to gradle version that you are using in your development environment

Answer (score 18):

You should download the latest [jdk](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)

Install it.

Then in Android Studio go to:

File-->Other Settings-->Default Project Structure

And change the location of the JDK Location for the new one:

[image]

Also set your java home to 1.8 by command line:

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)
```

Comment: Does not work for me

Comment: Is the `export JAVA_HOME=...` step necessary? And why? 
The first step (setting the JDK location) was the working solution for me on Android Studio as of 8.9.16

Comment: Thanks! You saved my life!

Comment: 1. Download and install the latest java version first. (www.java.com)
2. Set JDK location to: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112

Answer (score 3):

I had to update my Android Studio to the latest version to solve the problem. My JAVA_HOME and JDK were well configurated and was not a problem of compilation/running version. I don't know why, but just solve it when I updated AS to latest version.