# Android 3.0 Canary build error: Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-studio-3.0

**Update:**
I solved it by the advice from https://stackoverflow.com/a/37712635/288724

This link did not provide a good solution for Android Studio
[Unsupported major.minor version 52.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489398/unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0)

But this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/37712635/288724 helped me out.

I saw many people met the similar problem before.
However, my *Android Studio 2.3.2* works totally fine, the problem just showed when I am using *Android Studio 3.0 Canary 1* with *kotlin* support.

The error information is as following:

```
Error:(1, 1) A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'. > java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/build/gradle/AppPlugin : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

Can anybody give me any suggestions? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Seemingly, you run AS or Gradle within a lower version of JRE than 1.8. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489398/unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0

Comment: I didn't find the right solution for AS. Should I modify my build.gradle file? There is no any suggestions on official website.

Comment: Finally I solved it from https://stackoverflow.com/a/37712635/288724. Thanks for your help too.  @hotkey

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unsupported major.minor version 52.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489398/unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0)