# IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1 , all java project can not be compiled

Tags: java, intellij-idea

When I upgrade IDEA from version 15.1 to 2016 all projects report the following compile time error：

> Error:Module '**' production: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/intellij/openapi/vfs/VfsUtil : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Env: `Mac`  `osx10.11` `jdk7` `maven3.3.9`

Who knows what the reasons, thanks!

Comment: Looks to me like something requires the Java 8 JDK. Likely you cannot run the new Intellij on a [now obsolete](https://java.com/en/download/faq/java_7.xml) version of Java...

Comment: Check this Thead http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489398/unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0