# Getting error when trying to run new project in Android Studio 2.2.1

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I just updated to Android Studio 2.2.1 for Mac. Then I updated the JDK to version 8. Tried to start a new project and run it. I got the following error:

Error:(1, 1) A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/build/gradle/AppPlugin : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

I also tried going back to JDK version 7 as it says on google site that JDK 8 is unstable for Mac. still got the same error.

Comment: I have the same problem in Windows. Because the new Android studio with new gradler has problem with 9-inch PNG, I tried to go to previous version. And this error was shown.

Comment: If somebody has this error in the gradle build: Try to use JDK 8 !

Comment: I had same error on CI serve.  I moved from JDK 7 to 8. it was fine.

Answer (score 73):

Check your android build tools dependencies. In your build.gradle if its something like:

```
classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:+"
```

It has likely downloaded the alpha of 2.2 and that can cause the error you are seeing.

Try

```
classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0"
```

If you are already using the right build tools version but keep getting this error, maybe one of the third party Android libraries you are using is causing the problem due to the same reason. You can force the dependency version to be used (including transitive) by changing

```
classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0"
```

to

```
classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0') {
        force = true
    }
```

Documentation: [gist](https://gist.github.com/cr7pt0gr4ph7/6cd6339eabc2056bc3e7) and [official gradle docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html#org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy:force(java.lang.Object[])).

Comment: Same problem in Windows, without update Android Studio. Problem solved swithcing to 2.1.0 as well! Try to never use '+' operator in dependencies to avoid this kind of issues (I've found this in a legacy code :/ ).

Comment: On creation of new project, studio added **"classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha4'**  this version automatically when there is an issue in alpha versions then why they are adding by there own? tho by changing to `gradle:2.1.0` fixed my issue.. but it's weird.

Answer (score 62):

[image: select Mark]

I was also facing same problem. I upgraded Android Studio and as it forced to  But we need to configure same in App Settings as well.

Comment: In case anyone else is looking for the menu above, this is in File->Project Structure->SDK Location.  This worked for me without having to set the build version back to 2.1.0 as in @EricMorentin answer, so maybe things have moved on now.

Answer (score 18):

You can try to update **JAVA_HOME** to point to JDK 8 location.

In my case, I've updated Android studio project's SDK settings, changed **java** version in my PATH env variable, but still this error occured. Only updating JAVA_HOME helped me.

Answer (score 13):

I was also facing the same problem. I upgraded Android Studio and as it forced to install JDK 8, downloaded and installed this as well. But we need to configure same in App Settings as well.

1. Select Project [Right click on the app module] -> Open Module Settings -> Select SDK Location from Left Menu - > Configured correct JDK Version i.e removed the old version and updated path of JDK. Save.
2. Sync Project.

Problem solved!

EDIT: Elaborated Project word.

Comment: For those searching for 'Project' mentioned in above solution, Right click on the app module -> Open Module Settings.

Comment: Also, I got it solved by checking the recommended option (Use embedded JDK) without installing JDK 8.

Answer (score 4):

If you are on **Jenkins**, check Java version in **Jenkins->Manage Jenkins->Global Tool Configuration->JDK**

I had to update mine to JDK 8.

Answer (score 4):

I had same error in 2.3 beta 1 ,

Fixed as follow :

Download latest java jdk 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

In Android Studio ,  go to File > Project Structure > SDK Location > select JDK Location path to point to the new jdk installed (Ex: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111 )

Done !

Answer (score 3):

Ufff, I changed like everything I was able to find to jdk 8 and still no result but then I found Gradle settings in Intellij (preferences > gradle > GradleJVM) and it was ofc wrong, changed that and woala.

Answer (score 0):

---

I meet the problem too, but I have changed nothing before it's happening. I think google is purposely. Google is trying to use openJDK instead of JDK because of the lawsuit between google and oracle. So, in the new version 2.2.0 of android, we found that there are some new files in the installed folder:

[android studio 2.1 files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Djmkg.png)

[android studio 2.2 files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOJmD.png)

Then, I think we have two method to fix it:

1. Change the JDK environment variable of your OS.
2. Just click menu File --> Project Structure, choose *Use embedded JDK (recommended)*. I chose this way and it work.

Good luck...

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem what is work for me is that .

Go
*File>Settings>(on the panel left)Build,Execution,Deployment . then click on *Gradle*

There is option to *Update Gradle*. Click on that it will time 3 to 4min and after that error gone.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to update Android Studio to v2.2.3, it includes a fix of JDK8:

- [Bug fix for a JDK8/Kotlin compiler + dx issue (issue 227729)](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/index.html)

It's solved my problem.