# failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources' when merging Layouts with Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

My grandle config

```
 sourceSets {
        main {
            res.srcDirs =
                    [
                            'src/main/res/layouts/ChatLayout',
                            'src/main/res/layouts/',
                            'src/main/res'
                    ]
        }
    }
```

The error i got when i try to apply the grandle changes

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> /Users/Desktop/Projekt/app/src/main/res/layouts/ChatLayout/activity_group.xml: Error: Unsupported type 'LinearLayout'
  /Users/Desktop/Projek/app/src/main/res/layouts/activity.xml: Error: Unsupported type 'include'
```

i also get the error 'The URI is not registered' in all files.
The errors appear because the xml files are in the folder layouts and not layout, but i think Grandle should handle that ?

Comment: Paste your activity.xml and activity_group.xml

Comment: Can you try `clean` -> `Rebuild` ?

Comment: @pRaNaY 

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/build/gradle/AppPlugin : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35937875/unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0-when-rendering-in-android-studio) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37312404/getting-error-when-trying-to-run-new-project-in-android-studio-2-2-1)

Comment: I had fixxed the problem with clean , but still get the same error when syncing Gradle

Comment: @Dipalishah this is how the first lines look https://pl.vc/ori2w i think that cause the errors