# running job in hadoop - ERROR

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, runtime-error

I'm trying to run a program in hadoop `~ $ Desktop/HadoopProject2016.jar input output` and i keep getting `this error` :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
>   hadoop_project_16/AggregateJob : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:803)   at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)     at
>   sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)

Also i dont know how to check the output... Is the error normal?

Comment: `Unsupported major.minor version 52.0` means you are using java 8 and it is not supported. Try changing to java 7?

Comment: [Unsupported major.minor version 52.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489398/unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0)

Comment: @Gangaraju I changed to java 7 but it still pops up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Check if your JRE (java version) of your project in your workspace(eg: eclipse properties window) is same as your java version in your machine from which you are running the hadoop jar command.

2) I am assuming that you are submitting the jar as
hadoop jar

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop jars, you need to check them. Make sure all jars are updated (better bring in the latest version for every jar) and compatible with each other. You can find the version dependencies at http://www.mvnrepository.com/