# Gradle build errors

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I am trying to run my very first android studio project (basic activity), but I am always facing a lot of errors, here is the output: (build.gradle file is also attached bellow)

> ```
> Information:Gradle tasks [:app:clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar,
> ```
>
> :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:assembleDebug]
>       :app:clean
>       :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:checkDebugManifest
>       :app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2340Library
>       :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72340Library
>       :app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2340Library
>       :app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72340Library
>       :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42340Library
>       :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2340Library
>       :app:prepareDebugDependencies
>       :app:compileDebugAidl
>       :app:compileDebugRenderscript
>       :app:generateDebugBuildConfig
>       :app:mergeDebugShaders
>       :app:compileDebugShaders
>       :app:generateDebugAssets
>       :app:mergeDebugAssets
>       :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:generateDebugResources
>       :app:mergeDebugResources
>       :app:processDebugManifest
>       :app:processDebugResources
>       :app:generateDebugSources
>       :app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
>       :app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl
>       :app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest
>       :app:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript
>       :app:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig
>       :app:mergeDebugAndroidTestShaders
>       :app:compileDebugAndroidTestShaders
>       :app:generateDebugAndroidTestAssets
>       :app:mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets
>       :app:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources
>       :app:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources
>       :app:processDebugAndroidTestResources
>       :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources
>       :app:mockableAndroidJar UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies
>       :app:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard
>       :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
>       :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
>       :app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:compileDebugSources
>       :app:buildInfoDebugLoader
>       :app:transformClassesWithExtractJarsForDebug
>       :app:transformClassesWithInstantRunVerifierForDebug
>       :app:transformClassesWithJavaResourcesVerifierForDebug UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders
>       :app:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug
>       :app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug
>       :app:transformResourcesAndNative_libsWithJavaResourcesVerifierForDebug
>   UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug
>       :app:transformClasses_enhancedWithInstant+reloadDexForDebug UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:incrementalDebugTasks
>       :app:prePackageMarkerForDebug
>       :app:fastDeployDebugExtractor
>       :app:generateDebugInstantRunAppInfo
>       :app:coldswapKickerDebug
>       :app:transformClassesWithInstantRunSlicerForDebug
>       :app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug
>       To run dex in process, the Gradle daemon needs a larger heap.
>       It currently has approximately 910 MB.
>       For faster builds, increase the maximum heap size for the Gradle daemon to more than 2048 MB.
>       To do this set org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048M in the project gradle.properties.
>       For more information see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html
>       Error:java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
>       Error:java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
>       Error:java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
>       Error:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>       Error:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>       Error:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
>       Error:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>       Error:    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>       Error:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
>       Error:    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>       Error:    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
>       Error:    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
>       Error:    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
>       Error:    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>       Error:    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       Error:    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>       Error:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
>       Error:    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>       Error:    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
>       Error:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
>       Error:    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
>       Error:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
>       Error:    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
>       Error:    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>       Error:    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>       Error:    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
>       Error:    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       Error:    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
>       Error:    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>       Error:Exception in thread "main" 
>       Error:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
>       Error:    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
>       Error:    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>       Error:java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
>       Error:    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
>       Error:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>       Error:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
>       :app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED
>       Error:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
>       Error:    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>       Error:    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>       Error:    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
>       Error:    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
>       Error:    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
>       Error:    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       Error:    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
>       Error:Exception in thread "main" 
>       Error:    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>       Error:    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       Error:    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>       Error:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
>       Error:    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>       Error:    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>       Error:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
>       Error:    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
>       Error:Exception in thread "main" 
>       Error:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
>       Error:    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>       Error:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
>       Error:    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
>       Error:Exception in thread "main" 
>       Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>
> > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException:
> >     com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
> >     java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
> >     com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
> >     org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
> >     'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin\java.exe'' finished with
> >     non-zero exit value 1
> >         Information:BUILD FAILED
> >         Information:Total time: 7.643 secs
> >         Information:61 errors
> >         Information:0 warnings
> >         Information:See complete output in console

and here is my **build.gradle** file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    } }

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    } }

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir }
```

I tried to clean an rebuild the project with no success.
Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unsupported major.minor version 52.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489398/unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the exception stacktrace, it says, that the fail was caused by:

> Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

This usually means, that you are trying to use some classes, compiled with the newer JDK version, then the one you use currently. In your case, you have something, that was compiled witj JDK 1.8, but you are trying to use it with JDK 1.7. You can update your JDK to 1.8 and try one more time. Otherwise, you have to find, what causes this fail and try to use an older version of this dependency. You can find more at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489398/unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0)

Comment: I am using this jdk (jdk1.8.0_92),

I am very new to android and that was not the best start for me, I will read the question you gave to me.

Comment: According to your log, you are using 1.7 `Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin\java.exe''`. Check one more time, which version you are running.

Comment: As a note, Android Studio may use different version of JDK, than one, you have provided in your JAVA_HOME or on the path. Check the project properties to check it.

Comment: Thank you alot, it was really just java version conflict, it was taking the jdk 1.7 instead of 1.8.
The problem is now solved, thanx.