# Can't use google maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I was trying to use google map in my app, but I keep getting this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:             org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

I tried cleaning and restarting the project, but it didin't work either. 
The same project worked well on my friend's PC, but it just doesn't work on mine!

this the gradle messages content:

```
    Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72300Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMediarouterV72300Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42300Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices920Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds920Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAdsLite920Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics920Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalyticsImpl920Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppindexing920Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppinvite920Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuth920Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuthBase920Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase920Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement920Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCast920Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCastFramework920Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesClearcut920Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesContextmanager920Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesDrive920Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesFitness920Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGames920Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGass920Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm920Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIdentity920Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIid920Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation920Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps920Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesNearby920Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPanorama920Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlaces920Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlus920Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesSafetynet920Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTagmanager920Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTagmanagerApi920Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTasks920Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesVision920Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWallet920Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWearable920Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalytics920Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalyticsImpl920Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAuth920Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAuthCommon920Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAuthModule920Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCommon920Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseConfig920Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCrash920Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseDatabase920Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseDatabaseConnection920Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseIid920Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseMessaging920Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseStorage920Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseStorageCommon920Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJava
:app:preDexDebug
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
Exception in thread "main" 
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
Exception in thread "main" 
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
Exception in thread "main" 
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 22.892 secs
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
Exception in thread "main" 
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

and that's the build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.win7.mapapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.0'
}
```

and this my MapsActivity.java code:

```
    package com.example.win7.mapapp;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }







    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(0, 0))
                .title("Marker"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Follow this link to get more information http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_google_maps.htm  It is a complete example about using google map in android application

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unsupported major.minor version 52.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489398/unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0)

Comment: If you only need Maps, then you really should just use the maps dependency, not every single Google play service

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The important part of all that gradle output is

> Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

This means you have the incorrect version of the JDK installed. Update your installation.

Comment: For clarification,  Java 7 is being used, but Java 8 is needed

Answer (score 3):

Build Tools version 24.0.2 requires Java 8.

The easiest fix would be to continue using Java 7 and change your Gradle to use Build Tools rev 23.0.3:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.win7.mapapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure it's installed as well:

[image]