# Unsopported major minor version 52, after installing Android N

Tags: java, android, adt

I am using Android Eclipse ADT plugin (yes!) . MY project was compiling all rght untill I installed Android N. After that I am getting the above error in eclipse . I am using jre7 to compile.

My suspicion is that ecipse is using the latest installed android build tools whic got changed to 24 after update. Let me know if I am right, and how to revert it to 23.

I have already tried all other answers in SO including changing java versin to 8. Nothing works.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39442004/4409409   For Eclipse, I believe you will need to add `sdk.buildtools=23.0.3` to the `project.properties` file.

Comment: Thanks for commenting I tried this , I get error :
Unable to resolve sdk.buildtools property value '23.0.3'