# HibernatePersistenceProvider : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 intellij

Tags: java, hibernate, intellij-idea, jdk1.7

i searched for this problem such

[How to fix java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi)

but the answer didnt work for me

i am using jdk 1.7 , i set the compiler to 1.7.0_79 which meant to be java 7 but when i run i still getting the error , i set the project byte code version to 1.7 but the same message

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/hibernate/jpa/HibernatePersistenceProvider : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

this exception happens when try to load the 
persistence.xml on this line

```
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
```

and in the java code on this line

```
    EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("sample");
```

Comment: the only way is to use java 8

Comment: Not sure how the link cannot help you.  Have you checked here? http://hibernate.org/orm/documentation/getting-started/  If you are using Hibernate 5.2 or later, you need to use JDK8.  The link you quoted DOES explain why

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had encountered the same issue while working on a project with Hibernate: `Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/hibernate/jpa/HibernatePersistenceProvider : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0`.

Updating IntelliJ and Maven project settings (as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489398/unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0)) to use the same Java version for compiling and running didn't fix the issue.

As noted by `Adrian Shum` before, if you want to use `Java 7` you have to check `Hibernate`-related libraries because `Hibernate 5.2 and later versions require at least Java 1.8` ([Hibernate System Requirements](http://hibernate.org/orm/documentation/getting-started/)).

In my case, downgrading the library version inside the POM file solved the problem, by changing

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.6.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

into

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, the way I could compile it using JDK7 was to add hibernate-jpamodelgen into my pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
        <version>5.x.x.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Adding this should resolve the issue, just select the version you were working on

Answer (score 0):

" Unsupported major.minor version " usually appears because you are compiling the java program with a bigger version of java than the one you're trying to run it with.

So in your case you compiled your application with java 7, but you probably are trying to run it with java 6 or smaller.

Change the version of java with which you run your application to match the one that you are compiling with (7 in your case).

Comment: i have latest jre , but it has no thing to do with this compiling problem i guss

Comment: `1.7.0_79` is NOT the latest.  Use JDK 8 or later.  And, it IS related to this compilation problem.

Answer (score 0):

As hibernate core version 5.2 and upper not support with JDK 1.7 . So Please change maven dependency into 5.1.x and lower version for JDK 1.7. But in all lower version of hibernate core have missing all class of "org.hibernate.jpa" package.

If you need hibernate persistence provider then get exception for not class found. So that you should add a new dependency.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

- After add this dependency if you still get not class found exception then add @EnableJpaRepositories for JPA repositories.