# Unsupported major.minor version Exception for sonar-scanner

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I am trying to analyze my source code using SonarQube. I am trying to use `sonar-scanner` as my tool to run analysis from command line. I followed the guidelines presented in this documentation article: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner

When I try to test the installation by running `sonar-scanner -h` I am getting the following error:

```
➜  ~ sonar-scanner -h
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/sonarsource/scanner/cli/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

From the error it looks like its not finding the right version for JAVA/JRE to run the cli tool. My understanding was that the tool should work with any Java 1.7+ version. I am using `Oracle JDK 1.7.0_55`. I also tried using `OpenJDK 1.8` but I am still getting the same error. I also checked my `JAVA_HOME` variable is set to the right JDK directory.

Any help in the right direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After Struggling with this for a while, I found the cause of the problem. The CLI is looking at your `JAVA_HOME` path variable to figure out the version of Java it needs to use. even tough the default `java` and `javac` commands were pointing to JDK 8, setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable to your JDK 8 root directory solved the issue.

Hope this helps other folks facing similar issue.

Answer (score 4):

this have been already answered at length here : [Unsupported major.minor version 52.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489398/unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0) and here : [How to fix java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi)

the rationale is that you're trying to execute Sonar on a Java 7 or lower when the sonar classes have been compiled for java 8 thus triggering this error.

Comment: As I have already stated in my question I have tried running the tool with both JDK 7 and JDK 8. I am still getting the same error.

Comment: as you said yourself in the question, "you have checked the JAVA_HOME environment variable" .... i'm sorry but aside from that i pointed you on the correct answer, your version of java executed was wrong...