# React native Unsupported major.minor version 52

Tags: android, react-native

When running

```
react-native run-android
```

in my project folder, I get the following error:`

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/build/gradle/AppPlugin : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

I've updated java to the latest version and made sure that I've got all the required build tool sdk versions installed:

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "myappId"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unsupported major.minor version 52.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489398/unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0)

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem. I resolved it as follow:

1. Updated my **JDK** to **1.8**
2. Changed **JAVA_HOME** environment variable to point to the folder of new JDK version

Make sure that you're using the new JDK (step 2).

Comment: Thanks – more detail: On OS X (El Capitain), I just googled for install JDK 1.8 and I got a download page from Oracle. I then ran the command, `/usr/libexec/java_home` which gave me the value I needed for JAVA_HOME, which I added to my ~/.bash_profile

Comment: This work for me, did not have to change the JAVA_HOME. thanks for the good answer. I thought that it did not support JDK 1.8 as when you develop on Android or Xamarin it not work well with JDK 1.8 at the moment