# Chrome is failing to launch with Selenium 2.53.0 and Chrome driver 2.25

Tags: eclipse, google-chrome, selenium

While I am trying to verify any test cases on chrome, it fails. The Chrome is launching but after that it is showing out of memory. As per chrome help page, I disabled all the chrome extensions and closed all the table also. Still facing the same problem. The test cases are going fine on firefox and IE [Please check screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpa4w.png)

**Getting following exception from selenium: when using selenium 2.53.1**

```
    Starting ChromeDriver 2.25.426923 (0390b88869384d6eb0d5d09729679f934aab9eed) on port 15091
Only local connections are allowed.
[2.164][SEVERE]: Unable to receive message from renderer
```

**Code:**

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\TestWorkspace\\Resources\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        Thread.sleep(500);
        driver.quit();
```

When I am trying with updated selenium version 3.0.1 getting following error:In this case chrome not even opening itself

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Add your code that throws this please, and TestNG xml could help too.

Comment: Also try the latest selenium.

Comment: @lauda : Hi Guys, I have updated my question with simple example for easy understanding. Please check. My chrome has latest version and using latest chrome driver 2.25

Comment: @Moshisho: I have updated with a simple example of my problem..Please check

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489398/unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0   This is a general issue. Code compiled with one version and executed with other. Probably compiled with java 8 and you have jre 7. Also check if you have multiple jre installed and which one is in system variable. You might need to install another java version, latest should be ok.

Comment: I followed the same steps as mentioned in that problem for eclipse. I have check my system where I have only java 1.7.0_79 and on eclipse Java Home I have set as C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79 as it is said. Still getting the same exception. In cmd I have checked my existing java version and my system veriable also. Everywhere it is same.