# Hive UDF Run:Getting error in create temporary function in hive

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, udf

Here I have written one simple replace word UDF in java.
Then I have exported that .java file and created jar file.

Same created jar file added in hive using

`Add jar jar file path ;`

then I am trying to create temporary function in hive but getting below error

```
create temporary function  functionname as 'javaprogrampkgname.javaprogramname.';
```

but for this am getting below error on terminal:

> FAILED: Execution Error, return code -101 from
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionTask. ReplaceUDFpkg/ReplaceUDF
>   : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Comment: seems like java version mismatch. check compile and runtime java are same

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unsupported major.minor version 52.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489398/unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0)

Comment: @Nimal Ram Sir, both Java compile and runtime version is same: both are java version "1.7.0_80"
javac 1.7.0_80

Comment: how did you check? how did you create the jar file?

Answer (score 1):

Finally got the cause of this error.

Yes, this error due to java version mismatch but as:

I have written, compiled and exported as JAR in eclipse and then this exported JAR trying to use in a different version of java, here due to version mismatch the JVM could  not able to call and find this JAR.

I have solved this issue by compiling  my java code and creating JAR in "1.7" version which set for my Hadoop home path.

Answer (score 0):

It should be the error of your different java version on the place where you created UDF and your hive java version.