# how to setup swagger-jaxrs-maven?

Tags: maven, swagger

I am trying to use "swagger-jaxrs-maven" plugin to generate RESTful API docs from the source code.

I followed this web site: 
[swagger-jaxrs-maven](https://github.com/greensopinion/swagger-jaxrs-maven)

but maven complained that it can't find this plugin, so I searched it on 
[maven central repository](http://search.maven.org/)

It only finds it under groupId com.greensopinion.swagger. So I changed it accordingly.

But now I get this error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   com.greensopinion.swagger:jaxrs-gen:1.3.0:generate (default) on
>   project treaty: Execution default of goal com.greensopinion.swagg
>   er:jaxrs-gen:1.3.0:generate failed: Unable to load the mojo 'generate'
>   in the plugin 'com.greensopinion.swagger:jaxrs-gen:1.3.0' due to an
>   API incompatibility:
>   org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException:
>   com/greensopinion/swagger/jaxrsgen/SwaggerJaxrsGeneratorMojo :
>   Unsupported major.mi nor version 52.0

I cleaned all my local maven repository and re-tried, it doesn't work.

My maven is 3.2.3 and JDK is 1.7.

My RESTful framework is Jersey2.17 with Jackson.

Any suggestion on how to make it work?

Comment: *maven complain it can't find this plugin* Can you share what dependency you used? But the problem is that this is a plugin that uses Java 8. You can't use, this version at least, with JDK 7. This is what *Unsupported major.minor version 52.0* is telling you.

Comment: Thanks, Tunaki, it works after I switched to JDK 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is not related to swagger or maven but to your JDK version (version 52.0 means a JDK 8 is expected).

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/35866015/779338 for mode details.

Furthermore, if you download the [pom.xml](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/cc/catalysts/swagger-jaxrs-maven-plugin/1.0.0/swagger-jaxrs-maven-plugin-1.0.0.pom) of swagger-jaxrs-maven available in maven central repository, you can see that a JDK8 (maven.compiler.source=1.8) has been used to generate a java 8 package (maven.compiler.target=1.8), then it can't be used with a JDK7.

Answer (score 0):

I have following Maven dependencies, it turns out fine.

For Swagger, Phillip project which just plug and play.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.phillip-kruger</groupId>
        <artifactId>apiee-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.8</version>
    </dependency>
```

JAVA EE - JAX-RS api

```
    <!-- Java EE -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Use JDK 1.8 or above. 
I use eclipse and wildly server.