# Eclipse not connect with android device in ubuntu

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu

I am trying to run my eclipse project on my android device. The project built successfully and no error but when I tried to run project i get the following error:

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Android Package Builder' on project 'SplashScreen'.
com/android/dx/command/dexer/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

I am working on ubuntu 14.04. In my android devices developer option is on and `adb devices` command also show my devices properly but devices are not shown in the run configuration of the eclipse.

My eclipse version is eclipse 3.8.1. I tried with other PC with eclipse mars which is worked with my device and I run the application from eclipse mars. But when I tried with my PC, the device is not shown in eclipse.

So how can I solve this problem?

Comment: I think Eclipse support for Android has ended.. I suggest you to go with Android Studio strongly for developing.

Comment: To add to Yash's answer, that specific error is a [java version mismatch](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35866015/1426565)

Comment: @Guardanis Yes i think java version is problem because first i build that project in other pc which has java version "1.8.0_101" and now i am import that project in my pc which has java version 1.7.
So how can i set jar file which is compatible to java version 1.7 in my project.