# Exception in thread "Unsupported major.minor version 52.0"

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am using ubuntu 14.0 lts. My java version is java version "1.8.0_111".
I am getting this error while running the following code.

```
package wrangler;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class BrowserInvocation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/home/arima/geckodriver.exe");

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    }

}
```

Comment: You seem to be using one version of java for compilation and another version while running it. Try javac -version and java -version in Ubuntu terminal. Share the result. Refer this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489398/unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi)

Comment: @RohitDodle both javac -version and java -version is same .("java version "1.8.0_111"). how to resolve ?

Comment: @Sidhartha Please confirm which IDE or tool you are using. The configuration in the tools could be causing this.