# Trouble installing Scala in Debian Jessie

Tags: linux, scala, apache-spark, debian

I want to install Apache Spark in Debian Jessie.

I have correctly installed Oracle Java 7, and followed the steps for the installation of Scala:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/src/scala
sudo tar -xvf scala-2.11.7.tgz -C /usr/local/src/scala/
nano .bashrc
export SCALA_HOME=/usr/local/src/scala/scala-2.11.7
export PATH=$SCALA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Despite the fact that I have checked each step several times, the following output is given when I check if Scala is correctly Installed (`scala -version`):

```
   diego@DESKTOP-M93VP0O:~$ scala -version
cat: (/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/)/release: No such file or directory
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: scala/tools/nsc/MainGenericRunner : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClassOrNull(ClassLoader.java:1070)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:414)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:412)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

I am a newbie in linux. I would like to know how I may fix the problem (I have followed the steps of the following video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eQ0nPdfVfc0).

Comment: Can you install Java 8?  [That is likely to fix your immediate problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35866015/1072626) (possible duplicate).  I suspect there is more going on because Scala 2.11 should be compatible with Java 7, so I wonder if the Scala you are trying to run is not the 2.11.7 you think.

Comment: Why don't just `apt-get install scala`?