# Unity - Unable to convert classes into dex format. (Unity Ads & Unity IAP)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I made a small Unity game for android that displays an ad after the player dies five times. Before implementing **Unity Ads** I was able to create apks.

When I implemented the ads(via the services tab) in test mode(By enabling the built in ads extension extension) I decided to also implement in app purchasing(also via the services tab). When I imported the related assets I decided to generate a new apk to test out the ads on an android device. It was then when I encountered the below error.

I tried to remove the **iap** assets and re-import my current assets but to no avail. After messing around importing and re-importing suddenly *Advertisement.IsReady* stopped returning true in the editor.

Looking around google one the reasons is duplicate **jar** files. Oddly enough, instead of **jar** files my project has **aar** files of which I do not have duplicates.

I am a bit stumped as how to fix this issue.

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to convert classes into dex format.
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe -Xmx2048M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="C:/Users/MyUser/AppData/Local/Android/sdk\tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\sdktools.jar" -

stderr[
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
    at SDKMain.main(SDKMain.java:127)
]
stdout[

]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommandInternal (System.String javaExe, System.String sdkToolsDir, System.String[] sdkToolCommand, Int32 memoryMB, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommandSafe (System.String javaExe, System.String sdkToolsDir, System.String[] sdkToolCommand, Int32 memoryMB, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

[image: .aar files]
[image: Unity Version]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

This is telling you that the classes were compiled with the JDK for Java 8. [(Source)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489398/unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0) However, your JDK is for Java 7 (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe). Download and install a newer JDK and try again.

Comment: Took me a week to test it out but that was the issue. Thank you kindly.