# gradlew app:dependencies does not work

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I want to see which library uses play-services.

I command `gradlew app:dependencies` in my Android Studio terminal. It throws this:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Projects\project\android\app\build.gradle' line: 18

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/build/gradle/AppPlugin : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

The 18th line of my app gradle is: `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`

Any ideas?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489398/unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0) is the exact same symptom.

Comment: show your `build.gradle`

Comment: Make sure you are using latest gradle plugin.

Comment: @Egemen Hamutçu can you please consider http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Run with Java 8.

52 missmatch:
https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2015/05/fixing-unsupported-majorminor-version.html

probably got this in build.gradle as well?

```
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8
```