# Exception in thread - Squirrel SQL Client

Tags: java, squirrel-sql

**Specs:**

Kali Linux

squirrel-sql-snapshot-20170214_2214

openjdk version "1.8.0_121"

OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-8u121-b13-3-b13)

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)

**Error:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: net/sourceforge/squirrel_sql/client/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried editing "/usr/local/squirrel-sql-snapshot-20170214_2214/squirrel-sql.sh" and changed "IZPACK_JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre" to IZPACK_JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre. I think its a bug that needs to be looked into.

Comment: Looks like it is a bug: https://sourceforge.net/p/squirrel-sql/bugs/1138/

Comment: Also, have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35866015/766755 as it looks related to your issue.