# java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/springframework/boot/gradle/plugin/SpringBootPlugin : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Tags: java, spring, gradle, spring-boot

My single `build.gradle` looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
compileJava {
    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8
}
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility sourceCompatibility
    targetCompatibility targetCompatibility
}


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
}


dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    runtime('com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

But `gradle clean build` produces:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:                    
Build file 'D:\objectsharingsystem\build.gradle' line: 16

* What went wrong:          
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'object-sharing-system'.
> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/springframework/boot/gradle/plugin/SpringBootPlugin : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

* Try:                      
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Looks like I use java 8 everywhere.

`java_home` set to java 8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was that I have changed `JAVA_HOME` **after** idea start and I run the `gradle build` from idea. Thus problem was resolved after idea restart

Comment: yes i changed the JAVA_HOME to correct jdk version and then it worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

I had similar issue when building with maven. In my case it appeared that project was built with jdk 1.8 but run on jdk 1.7.

This topic helped me getting into this issue: [Unsupported major.minor version 52.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489398/unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0)

Answer (score 0):

For me, I'm using Gradle. It is because I previously configured `USER_HOME/.gradle/gradle.properties` file to use jdk version 7. So, it will not use JAVA_HOME.

Solution is to remove gradle.properties file.