# Roboeletric - java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError

Tags: android, robolectric

I have create new android studio project and below is the gradle file where i didnt changed anything apart from compileSDKVersion

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "retailstore.android.com.tddandroid"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    // import roboeletric

    testCompile "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.3.2"


}
```

Android i wrote my first roboeletric test as below :

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class MainActivityTest {

    @Test
    public void clickingLogin_shouldStartLoginActivity() {

        assertThat("").isEqualTo("");
    }
}
```

I m running test via command prompt as below :

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35866015/3329708

Comment: What version of android gradle plugin do you use? Gradle has already version 3.5, probably time to update also (in your wrapper)

Comment: @EugenMartynov this is gradle plugin i m using `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
`

Comment: Almost recent, can you upgrade gradle?

Comment: @EugenMartynov i tried but somehow it did worked

Comment: @EugenMartynov it got resolved with upgrading JDK from 1.7 to 1.8

Comment: Clear, I was thinking that you're already on jdk 1.8. Cool! congrats!

Comment: Write an answer, so everyone can benefit from your problem

Comment: @EugenMartynov thx

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you check with robolectric version is compatible with with version of java :

Robolectric 24+ api version need JDK 1.8 .

It may be possible that 1.7 and 1.8 both JDK version are been installed on your machine for mac do check which all version are being installed with below command :

```
$ ls -l /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel  102 Nov  4  2013 jdk1.7.0_45.jdk
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel  102 Jan 16 14:13 jdk1.8.0_25.jdk
```

Switch the JDK version appropriately