# tomcat 7 project from eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, jakarta-ee, tomcat7

I have a base project that worked well in my prod server Tomcat 7.

I imported it in Eclipse, created a tomcat 7 server to run it and did some development. 
Everything work fine in eclipse browser but when i exported the war file and put it in `webapps` folder on my prod server i got the following error :

```
FAIL - Application at context path /art_current could not be started
```

For information, my Prod tomcat is under Java7 so i changed my project build path and java compiler in 1.7.

I tried to create a context.xml file in META-INF folder:

```
<Context path="/art_current" />
```

but still get the same error

I have noticed something, when i export my project by Eclipse, the project structure is altered :

> **Basic Project :**

[image]

> **Exported project from Eclipse :**

[image]

As we can see, there is some new folders and in particular a **META-INF** folder appeared, is it normal ?

Maybe i am doing something wrong but i can't find what

**EDIT**

here are the log i get when i try to start my app from tomcat manager :

> **catalina.log**

```
avr. 24, 2017 4:54:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFOS: TLD skipped. URI: http://cewolf.sourceforge.net/taglib/cewolf.tld is already defined
avr. 24, 2017 4:54:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFOS: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
avr. 24, 2017 4:54:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
GRAVE: One or more Filters failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
avr. 24, 2017 4:54:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
GRAVE: Erreur de démarrage du contexte [/art_current] suite aux erreurs précédentes
```

> **localhost.log**

```
avr. 24, 2017 4:54:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
GRAVE: Exception au démarrage du filtre exportPathFilter
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: art/servlets/ExportPathFilter : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class art.servlets.ExportPathFilter)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:3209)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1373)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1861)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1735)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:486)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:113)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4958)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5652)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1312)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:216)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:615)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

avr. 24, 2017 4:54:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
GRAVE: Exception au démarrage du filtre AuthFilterAdmin
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: art/servlets/AuthFilterAdmin : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class art.servlets.AuthFilterAdmin)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:3209)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1373)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1861)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1735)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:486)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:113)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4958)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5652)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1312)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:216)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:615)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

avr. 24, 2017 4:54:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
GRAVE: Exception au démarrage du filtre AuthFilter
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: art/servlets/AuthFilter : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class art.servlets.AuthFilter)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:3209)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1373)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1861)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1735)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:486)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:113)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4958)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5652)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1312)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:216)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:615)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: All circumstantial material. What you need to be looking for is a clear indicator why the project fails when deployed as a war. There has to be more to it than only the deployment failure message, check the server log file.

Comment: @Gimby Thx for reply, you can look at my edit. It seems that some classes cannot be loaded. But how it's possible if it work in Eclipse ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following solution:

In the log file we can see :

```
Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

As we can see here : [Unsupported major.minor version 52.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489398/unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0)

It's because my eclipse compiled my project in Java 1.8 and my tomcat was running in 1.7. Even if i changed my project build path and compiler in 1.7 under Eclipse( + clean and rebuild).

So i just switched my Tomcat java version from 1.7 to 1.8 and everything now work fine.