# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. - React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm Testing My React Native Installation 
First

```
react-native start
```

After That

```
react-native run-android
```

I Connected my Device to pc, But I have This Error:

```
Scanning 557 folders for symlinks in D:\Projects 2016\Web\Android\FirstApp\AwesomeProject\node_modules (15ms)
JS server already running.
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat installDebug)...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'D:\Projects 2016\Web\Android\FirstApp\AwesomeProject\android\app\build.gradle' line: 1

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/build/gradle/AppPlugin : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2.533 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to the issue related with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489398/unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0).

And the [react-native docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html) indicates that it requires latest version of [JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).

Update your JDK version to latest one.