# ionic android app build failed .its brings this error how can i solve it

Tags: ionic-framework, build, ionic2

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 14.48 secs
Error: /home/matynjr/techlyt/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file '/home/matynjr/techlyt/platforms/android/build.gradle' line: 20
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

  > java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/build/gradle/AppPlugin : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unsupported major.minor version 52.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489398/unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0)

Comment: I'd try to remove android platform and re add it back and then do a build.  I remember when I opened AndroidStudio it asked me to update gradle..I did and all went to hell for the build.

Answer (score 0):

actually i solved the problem by setting my java home variable and path

Comment: I met the same problem? Can you give more details? Thank you.