# Maven Android: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Tags: java, android, maven, maven-3

When I try building my android project with the following:

**Maven**: apache-maven-3.3.9,

**JDK**: jdk1.7.0_79

I get the following error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
  at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
  at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

Can anyone please help?

Thank you.

My pom is as follows:

```
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.concretepage</groupId>
    <artifactId>AndroidDemo</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <packaging>apk</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-android-rest-template</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.simpleframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>simple-xml</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>stax</artifactId>
                    <groupId>stax</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>stax</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>xpp3</artifactId>
                    <groupId>xpp3</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>xmlParserAPIs</artifactId>
                    <groupId>xerces</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>    
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>            
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
              <plugin>
                <groupId>com.simpligility.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.4.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <sdk>
                        <platform>23</platform>
                    </sdk>
                    <deleteConflictingFiles>true</deleteConflictingFiles>
                    <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
                    <resourceDirectory>${basedir}/res</resourceDirectory>
                    <androidManifestFile>${basedir}/AndroidManifest.xml</androidManifestFile>
                </configuration>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
              </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Project structure as follows:

[image]

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489398/unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0

Comment: i checked it out.. but my issue is that i want to build with JDK 1.7. and it is asking for version 52.0 which refers to JDK 1.8.i will import this project in eclipse afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

The error `java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0` means that the class **com.android.dx.command.Main** included in one of your dependancies is compiled in Java 1.8 (version 52.0)

Change to Java 1.8 and that should work

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: If you're target runtime is java7 you can try getting away with setting source to 1.8 and target to 1.7. This way you don't have to worry about updating your java runtime.

Comment: i changed everything java8 and now get:  unsupported class file version 52.0