# java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/openqa/selenium/Capabilities : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Tags: java

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/openqa/selenium/Capabilities : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2570)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2813)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1663)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
```

I am using Java 1.7.0_60 I am getting above error when am run the program in eclipse

Comment: Check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489398/unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0

Comment: Probably the selenium that you are using requires Java 8.

Comment: You need to use a v2 release of Selenuim on Java 7. v3 is for Java 8 only. See: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/master/java/CHANGELOG