# Android 2D Game Development Using UNITY Game Engine

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, libgdx, 2d, game-engine

need a small suggestion

i am a beginner in android development and i have developed some basic apps and now i have been given a project in which i have to make the game exactly like "**Color Switch**" game most of you have played this game, its famous with 100 million downloads.

[Color Switch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/058NC.png)

So my doubt is that , since this is a 2-D game, do i have to use game engine or not, if game engine must be used which one is preferable, **Unity** or **LIBGDX**? i am confused to choose and also i would be thankful if you give me link to some tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're developing game you should use Game Engine because Game engine have inbuilt many features that required for game Development. like Action, Particle Effect, Physics Engine integration and more....

Then which Game Engine ?

It's only a matter of choice :)

1. Depending upon type of game 2D, 2.5D or 3D
2. Language choice like you're good in Java, C# , C++ or any other language.
3. Static game or Dynamic game in which fps is bottle neck problem.
4. Commercial or Open source
5. Cross platform game deployment or not.
6. Tutorial or Community help
7. And many more...

---

Color-Switch developed using [BuildBox](https://www.buildbox.com/) but that is not free, you've to pay some licensing fee.

I love to suggest `LibGDX` for color-switch. For 2D game development LibGDX is quite good than Unity and second thing LibGDX is open source.

Comment: Thanks Aryan for the answer, as i said i wanna make COLOR SWITCH game, so what with what engine will you suggest me to proceed with?

Comment: i am trying to install libgdx and i am getting this error, pls see the image attached in the link below. it is saying build failed
http://imgur.com/a/eom0g

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi) and more specifically [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489398/unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0)

Comment: @Hllink yeah LibGDX is not a game engine but here I m just using `game engine` keyword as to refer game development API/Framework.

Comment: yeah, just to keep informed, usually someone who's starting may prefer go with an engine because it's easier, so he doesn't need to know how to handle an render method, lot of math and multiple other principles to build a game, i love libgdx but you need a lot more knowledge to start a simple project.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a matter of opinion, and it's different for everyone. I like using Unity, but that's just because I've been using it for years. You should try out both engines and see which one you prefer.

Here are some Unity tutorials:
https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials.
Here, you work through a series of projects guided by videos.

LIBGDX tutorials:
http://www.gamefromscratch.com/page/LibGDX-Tutorial-series.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link for LIBGDX tutorials Dan , but these tuts are in pure java, can u please give me some which are in android so that it will be easy for me to get away with it fast and clear.

Answer (score 0):

Sor for my english. LibGdx - java. Unity - c#. If you have a bad computer, unity better then android studio (unity is faster. I know, you can do a game on eclipse - not android studio, - but i dont know about eclipse speed). You can to do 2d on uniy and libgdx. But my opinion - unity easy, then libgdx (again, sor fo my english). I mean work with screen resolution and other things (not programming). You need to write programm code on libgdx and on unity. But if you want, you can to do game without game engine. And again, sor for my english