# How to resolve namenode not starting?

Tags: java, hadoop

Namenode is not starting and is throwing the following error message:

> 17/08/17 03:45:16 ERROR namenode.NameNode: Failed to start namenode.
>   java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
>   org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/SequenceFileAsBinaryOutputFormat
>   : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

I'm unsure what the issue is. Is there a way to resolve this issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489398/unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0