# Tomcat7: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: filepath: Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

Tags: java, tomcat7

I have set JAVA_HOME with

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk.1.7.0_80
```

at system environment variable, restarted the pc, but I am still unable to run the web application at Tomcat Web Application Manager with the following exception.

```
Oct 3, 2017 9:56:05 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter naviox
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/forms/model/ProjectDemo: Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (unable to load class org.forms.model.ProjectDemo)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:3209)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1373)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1861)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1735)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:224)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:242)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.buildHibernateConfiguration(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1136)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:853)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:425)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:849)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:54)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
    at org.openxava.jpa.XPersistence.getEntityManagerFactory(XPersistence.java:197)
    at org.openxava.jpa.XPersistence.createManager(XPersistence.java:112)
    at org.openxava.component.parse.AnnotatedClassParser.obtainManagedClassNamesUsingJPA(AnnotatedClassParser.java:2651)
    at org.openxava.component.parse.AnnotatedClassParser.getManagedClassNames(AnnotatedClassParser.java:2566)
    at com.openxava.naviox.impl.BaseAllModulesNamesProvider.getAllModulesNames(BaseAllModulesNamesProvider.java:19)
    at com.openxava.naviox.impl.AllModulesNamesProvider.getAllModulesNames(AllModulesNamesProvider.java:14)
    at com.openxava.naviox.impl.MetaModuleFactory.createAll(MetaModuleFactory.java:34)
    at com.openxava.naviox.impl.DB.createModules(DB.java:130)
    at com.openxava.naviox.impl.DB.populateDB(DB.java:86)
    at com.openxava.naviox.impl.DB.populateDB(DB.java:78)
    at com.openxava.naviox.impl.DB.init(DB.java:27)
    at com.openxava.naviox.Modules.init(Modules.java:38)
    at com.openxava.naviox.web.NaviOXFilter.init(NaviOXFilter.java:22)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5652)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1312)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:683)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:209)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:615)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I have tried with jdk1.8 and it displays the same exception. I can't figure out where I did wrongly. Please help and thanks.

P.S: I am using Windows 7

Comment: install tomcat 8

Comment: Have you seen these questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489398/unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi

Comment: Yes. I am not using any IDE to run the tomcat. I include the .WAR file at tomcat/webapps and run it on tomcat web application manager.