# Error: invalid LOC header (bad signature) / Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, google-fabric

```
Error: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
```

for `apply plugin: 'io.fabric'`

Fabric support team suggested to run

```
gradlew assemble --refresh-dependencies
```

Then I face following issue

**BUILD FAILED**

> - What went wrong:
>     A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
>     java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/build/gradle/AppPlugin : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

**Developement Environment:**

Gradle Version 4.1

Android Studio 3.0.1

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

compileSdkVersion 26

buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

Using embadded JDK of Android Studio

**Note:** If I comment `apply plugin: 'io.fabric'` project get build successfully.

Comment: Run `java -version` and `javac -version` within the console in Android Studio - what version does it show? This error is almost always down to a difference in JDK compile version between the library and your PC.

Comment: @MichaelDodd got this -> java version "1.7.0_79"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)

Comment: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35866015/469080) you'll need to install the Java 8 JDK as it looks like Fabric was compiled against that. Java 7 = version 51.0, Java 8 = version 52.0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi)

Comment: Okay let me try that