# Can not run Grails project from NetBeans

Tags: grails, netbeans-8

I can create and run a Grails project from command prompt. But whenever I want to run the project from NetBeans

```
Error |
Failed to compile CreateScaffoldController.groovy: geb/transform/AttributeAccessingMetaClassRegisteringTransformation : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
Error |
Command [run-app] error: null (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

this error occurs.

I am using Grails version: 3.3.2

NB: I also can not create Grails project from NetBeans. Though I have installed Grails plugins in the NetBeans.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489398/unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unsupported major.minor version 52.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489398/unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0)