# Downloading scientific workflow kepler: Error ant in build .xml

Tags: cmd, ant, workflow

When I try to download my kepler engine using cmd, I face this problem for the ant in the `build.xml`. I install the java, ant, and svn versions, and I don't have any problems.

> C:\Users\lenovo\kepler\build-area>ant  change-to -Dsuite=kepler
>   Buildfile: C:\Users\lenovo\kepler\build-area\build.xml
>
> BUILD FAILED
>   C:\Users\lenovo\kepler\build-area\build.xml:4: The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   C:\Users\lenovo\kepler\build-area\settings\taskdefs.xml:5: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/kepler/build/Maven : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.defineClassFromData(AntClassLoader.java:1150)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.getClassFromStream(AntClassLoader.java:1318)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.findClassInComponents(AntClassLoader.java:1374)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.findClass(AntClassLoader.java:1335)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.loadClass(AntClassLoader.java:1090)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:278)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Definer.addDefinition(Definer.java:580)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Definer.execute(Definer.java:238)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
>           at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:437)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.ProjectHelper2.parse(ProjectHelper2.java:169)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ImportTask.importResource(ImportTask.java:225)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ImportTask.execute(ImportTask.java:166)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
>           at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:437)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.ProjectHelper2.parse(ProjectHelper2.java:180)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.configureProject(ProjectHelper.java:93)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:832)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:236)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:286)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:112)
>
> Total time: 0 seconds

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unsupported major.minor version 52.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489398/unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Kepler FAQ "system requirements"](https://kepler-project.org/users/faq#section-UserFAQ-WhatAreTheSystemRequirem) explicitly states:

> Kepler is a large application that has substantial hardware requirements.
>   These include 512MB of RAM (1 GB or more recommended), at least 300 MB of disk space, and at least a 2GHz CPU. Kepler runs on modern Windows, Macintosh (OS X), and **Linux systems using Java 1.8 or greater**.

As [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35866015/6309), you error message means you are not using the right JDK. (JDK8 or more)

Check out [Instructions and Overview of the Kepler Build System. / Assumptions](https://kepler-project.org/developers/teams/build/documentation/build-system-instructions#assumptions)

> 1. You are running Java 1.8. To test this assumption type: "java -version"
> 2. You are using Ant 1.8.2. To test this assumption type: "ant -version"
> 3. You have installed Maven 3.0.3 or newer. To test this assumption: "mvn --version"
> 4. You have installed an SVN client, v1.6. To test this assumption type: "svn --version"
> 5. For development with Eclipse these have been tested with Eclipse Ganymede and SVN 1.5.5,
>      with Subclipse 1.4.7.