# Could not find the main class JAR

Tags: java, compilation

I compile this:

```
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\javac" -cp lib\* src\*.java -d classes
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\jar" -cfmv jar\TestClient.jar Manifest.txt -C classes .
```

Manifest.txt contains:

```
Main-Class: JmsClient
```

In "classes" folder:

```
JmsClient.class
JmsClient$1.class
```

And I have this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: AluSamoNbiJmsClient : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Could not find the main class: JmsClient
```

Comment: Just to be sure, can you check that all class files are where they should be in the jar (open it in a zip viewer). Also, that the package declaration is correct.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: AluSamoNbiJmsClient : Unsupported major.minor version 52.
And I have this exception

Comment: This I know what this means. You compiled with java 8 but executed with java 7 or lower.

Comment: I run with 1.8.0_144
and
I compile with 1.8.0_162

How to solve?

Comment: Try running with 1.8.0_162

Comment: It's not possible, because I run in production server

Comment: Then try compiling with 1.8.0_144

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489398/unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0

Comment: thanks kutschkem. i add flag -target 1.8 -source 1.8 and it's work!