# Not able to load data from postgresql to hdfs using tSqoopImport

Tags: postgresql, sqoop, talend, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I am using talend big data version 6.5.1 (has Java 8) and cloudera quickstart CDH 5.12 (has java 7).

I am tryiing to load table 'employees' from postgresql to hdfs using talend tSqoopImport component.

But I am getting error

`Error employees : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0`

Need help

Answer (score 0):

This issue belongs to JAVA version.

You have used different java version java 7 and 8.

Try it with same java 7.

Issue will be resolved.

For your reference.

[Unsupported major.minor version 52.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489398/unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But Talend 6.5.1 does not support java 7. I will not able to open the talend studio if I change it.

Comment: Ok. Try with CDH to java8

Comment: I checked that. But I am not sure after upgrading to java 8 my CDH services would work fine. Is there any option like how can I build my existing talend job in java 7 and run?

Comment: No idea about talend tool