# Running a Java program with different JRE?

Tags: java, windows, java-8, compilation

In my work Windows computer, the system path for JAVA_HOME is stuck at JAVA 1.6(and I don't have access to change "System" environment variables). I need to compile and run a program with Java 8. I was able to successfully compile the program by getting a java 1.8 jdk from a co-worker and  adding its path to the command line before executing the maven build command but when I attempt to run the program, I get the "Unsupported major.minor version 52" error([Unsupported major.minor version 52.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489398/unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0?rq=1)). Is there a way to run the program without modifying the "System variables"(I do have access to change the "User Variables").

Comment: Have you tried specifying it as a user variable? User `PATH` variables are appended to the system's `PATH` variable. I'm unsure of how this will affect referencing: will this cause a conflict error? Will the JRE specified at the end of the `PATH` take precedence over preceding defined JREs? Will the JRE closest to the beginning of the `PATH` be accepted, causing following JRE entries to be ignored?  Have you tried this?

Answer (score 1):

You can call `C:\Program Files\Java\<YOUR DESIRED JVM>\bin\java.exe` and then add your command line parameters

For example

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin\java.exe -jar my-awesome-jar.jar

Use within quotes if path has space.

For example

"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin\java.exe" -jar my-awesome-jar.jar