# Error: it/crs4/pydoop/mapreduce/pipes/Submitter : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 CentOS6 , Pydoop, Hue , Cloudera

Tags: mapreduce, centos, pip, cloudera, hue

When I try to run the script, I get this error. This is a Python script. Does anyone have this problem?

```
[cloudera-scm@ivana-namenode2 /opt/MapReduce/wordcount]$ pydoop script wc.py   /user/cloudera-scm/MapReduce/wordcount/data/text /user/cloudera-scm/MapReduce/wordcount/output
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: it/crs4/pydoop/mapreduce/pipes/Submitter : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
ERROR - RunCmdError:  command exited with 1 status
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to get the most out of this site.

Answer (score 1):

When you turn to this existing [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489398/unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0) you find the explanation for the error message: you have *some* java class that was compiled for Java8.

But the JVM asked to *execute* that class is *older* than Java8.

In other words: you have an inconsistent setup. Some part of your environment wants to use something build for Java8, but that part that *executes* things is running an older version of Java.

So, the answer here is that *you* have to understand better what your setup is composed of, to either use an "older" version of the underlying library/tool, or to make sure that a Java8 JVM is available to run classes.

Comment: Your answer is not solution. I had problem with pydoop. But thanks

Comment: Then you might want to add a self-answer. The whole point here is to answer questions for future readers, not just the person first "reporting" an issue ...