# How to convert python xgboost model into the pmml?

Tags: python-3.x, regression, xgboost, pmml

How to convert python xgboost model into the pmml ?

```
reg = XGBRegressor(learning_rate=0.1, n_estimators=30, max_depth=4, min_child_weight=4, gamma=0.1,
                       subsample=0.9, colsample_bytree=0.8, objective='binary:logistic', reg_alpha=1,
                       scale_pos_weight=1, seed=27)
param_test = [{
        'max_depth': [i for i in range(1, 3)],
        'gamma': [i / 10.0 for i in range(0, 10)],
        'n_estimators': [i for i in range(2, 14, 2)],
}]
gsearch = GridSearchCV(reg, param_grid=param_test, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error', n_jobs=4, iid=False, cv=5)
gsearch.fit(x_train, y_train)
best_model = gsearch.best_estimator_
```

Answer (score 2):

See the SkLear2PMML package: https://github.com/jpmml/sklearn2pmml

First, define a new pmml pipeline, and insert your XGBRegressor into it. Then, fit the pmml pipeline using the `GridSearchCV` learner. Finally, export the `GridSearchCV.best_estimator_` - which shall be the optimized pmml pipeline - into PMML data format using the `sklearn2pmml.sklearn2pmml` function call:

```
pmml_pipeline = PMMLPipeline([
  ("regressor", XGBRegressor())
])
tuner = GridSearchCV(pmml_pipeline, ...)
tuner.fit(X, y)
sklearn2pmml(tuner.best_estimator_, "xgbregressor-pipeline.pmml")
```

Also see slide #26 of the following presentation: https://www.slideshare.net/VilluRuusmann/converting-scikitlearn-to-pmml

Comment: i tried this way, but it's has error like :Invalid parameter gamma for estimator PMMLPipeline(steps=[('regressor', XGBRegressor(base_score=0.5, booster='gbtree', colsample_bylevel=1,
       colsample_bytree=0.8, gamma=0.1, learning_rate=0.1,
       max_delta_step=0, max_depth=4, min_child_weight=4, missing=nan,
       n_estimators=30, n_jobs=1, nthread=None,
       objective='binary:logistic', random_state=0, reg_alpha=1,
       reg_lambda=1, scale_pos_weight=1, seed=27, silent=True,
       subsample=0.9))]). Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`.

Comment: The error message "Invalid parameter gamma for estimator (PMML)Pipeline" means that you must prepend a step identifier to all your grid search parameter names. For example, `max_depth` should become `regressor__max_depth`, and so on. See https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/9944

Comment: thank you, and i have another question, when i tried to covert to pmml, it's has a error like:RuntimeError: The JPMML-SkLearn conversion application has failed. The Java executable should have printed more information about the failure into its standard output and/or standard error streams.     i want to know how to fix this problem

Comment: The error is: `java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/jpmml/sklearn/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0`. It means that your `java.exe` version does not support Java (1.)8 class files. Uninstall the current `java.exe`, and install the latest one.

Comment: More info about this error is here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489398/unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0

Comment: thank you, i tried update my java version to jdk.1.8, and here is  another problem like:UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd4 in position 2: invalid continuation byte, can you teach me how to fix it.

Comment: The `UnicodeDecodeError` happens because your `java.exe` is printing log messages using a charset that is not UTF-8. See here for more discussion: https://github.com/jpmml/sklearn2pmml/issues/122 The fix is to specify `java_encoding` attribute to the `sklearn2pmml` function call. Something like `sklearn2pmml(tuner.best_estimator_, "xgbregressor-pipeline.pmml", java_encoding = ...)`

Comment: thank you, i checked the sklearn2pmml/_init_.py, it is the new version and it is same  with the style you give me in the github.com, and i also tried add java_encoding = 'UTF-8'(sklearn2pmml(tuner.best_estimator_,'xgbregressor_pipeline.pmml',java_encoding="UTF-8")) but it still has the same problem, i have no idea how to fix it.  I read the data like: data = pd.read_csv('D:\\xgboost\\ivceshi.csv',encoding = 'ANSI'),  i want to know could this problem cuz by the encoding = 'ANSI'?