# How to fix problem 'Unsupported major.minor version 52.0' when trying to start Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat

I want to start service Logstash in my server, but when I trying to start, I got warning info log. Is it any problem solved for this issue?

All of my setting was same with information as on web, start from configuration on startup.option, jvm.option, logstash.yml and logstash-sample.conf but when I try to start, it thorws below error :

> [root@CDS01~/logstash]$./bin/logstash -e warning: ignoring
>   JAVA_OPTS=-Dsysid=CTAG_WEB_SERVER -DCTAG_CONFIG=/app1/am/cds -server
>   -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:ParallelGCThreads=2 -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=50; pass JVM parameters via LS_JAVA_OPTS

Answer (score 1):

This issue happens when some of your libraries are compiled using different JRE version, then your running JRE version.

You must be using some incompatible versions of JAR in your application. let me know which version of Logstash and which JDK you are using and any site which you are following to install and run your application?

Please refer this [Unsupported major.minor version 52.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489398/unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0) SO question on detailed explanation about it.

Please check the Logstash site for the compatible JDK version based on your version.

**Looks like you are using some of the jars which are compiled using JRE 8, while you are using the JRE 7 or lower which are causing the issue**, Please refer [How to fix java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi) of more information on different class versions of JRE and how to fix this exception.

Comment: can you show me, how-to know what version of my logstash ? 

for JDK :
$java -version
java version "1.7.0_09-icedtea"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.3.4.1.el6_3-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.2-b09, mixed mode)

but I've already another JDK in my server :

/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_92/bin

Comment: you must have downloaded from site, btw if you just use JDK 8, then I am almost sure this exception will go

Comment: @ImamFauzi , were you able to figure out the logstash version, if not you can use https://serverfault.com/questions/759583/get-logstash-version and also did you try using Jre 8 to run your logstash?

Comment: it's my version :

[root@CDS01~/home/content-delivery/temp/logstash]$./bin/logstash --version
warning: ignoring JAVA_OPTS=-Dsysid=CTAG_WEB_SERVER -DCTAG_CONFIG=/app1/am/cds -server -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:ParallelGCThreads=2 -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=50; pass JVM parameters via LS_JAVA_OPTS
logstash 7.0.1