# Cannot run ElasticSearch-7.5.0 on Linux(SUSE)

Tags: linux, elasticsearch, suse

I am trying to run ES on my server, and I got this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/elasticsearch/tools/java_version_checker/JavaVersionChecker : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
```

Could not find the main class: org.elasticsearch.tools.java_version_checker.JavaVersionChecker.  Program will exit.

It seems that the issue is related to the java version, Could you please advise if I do something wrong or there a special configuration should be taken before running the ES?

Please note that we have the following JDK versions install in the server:

- jdk1.7.0_25_32bit
- jdk1.7.0_25_64bit
- jdk1.7.0_72_32bit
- jdk1.7.0_72_64bit
- jdk1.8.0_74_64bit

Comment: Were u able to resolve the issue?

Comment: Hello @OpsterESNinja, I have pointed to JDK 1.8 inside the application config and the cluster is up. many thanks for the help.

Comment: Has been done :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest version of elasticsearch is not compatible with older version of Java and more details on the generic error `Unsupported major.minor version 51.0` can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56880702/how-to-fix-problem-unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0-when-trying-to-start-l).

Also as mentioned in [this official ES doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup.html#jvm-version), ES will not start if compatible version of JVM isn't found.

> Elasticsearch will refuse to start if a known-bad version of Java is
>   used. The bundled JVM directory may be removed when using your own
>   JVM.

And the entire supported version of JVM with a different version of elasticsearch can be found in this [officially supported matrix link](https://www.elastic.co/support/matrix#matrix_jvm).

Going through your error message, it is clear that you are using 1.7 JDK version which uses `51` as a major version as mention in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11432195/4039431) SO answer. and if you check the above-supported matrix, on or after ES 5.X there isn't any support for less than JDK 1.8 version.

**Hence you need to point your JDK to 1.8 version as its already installed in your system but not being used and there are a plethora of documents available on how to do it and after that, you should be able to start ES.**