# JBOSS Server stucks in starting state

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8, jboss, jboss-eap-7

I am using JBOSS EAP 7.2 on STS 3.4 with JDK 1.8.
STS 3.4 do not have adapter specific to JBOSS EAP 3.4, So I am using it in the JBoss EAP 6.1+ Runtime Server adapter service itself.

And when I try to start my server, the server gets started.
It shows on console like this,

```
17:22:18,999 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: JBoss EAP 7.2.0.GA (WildFly Core 6.0.11.Final-redhat-00001) started in 16013ms - Started 628 of 815 services (356 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

But on the Eclipse(STS 3.4) processes it shows that it starting.
It keeps in that state until it reaches timeout and then it stops.

I tried many of the solutions but nothing seems to working. I tried changing the the `startup poller` in server state detectors to `web port` instead of `JBOSS 7 manager service`. It gives the server status as started as soon as the server gets started.

But then It gives another error,

```
An internal error occurred during: "Connecting to JBoss EAP 6.1+ Runtime Server via JMX".
org/jboss/remotingjmx/RemotingConnectorProvider : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

And then, It also gives problem in the stopping process. After changing this the server is unable to stop

I want to know why this is happening and what is prominent solution for this. And is there any links available regarding this issue which I can refer.

Comment: Reference for the last error (unsupported major.minor 52.0): https://stackoverflow.com/q/22489398/243373. It means that Java 8.0 not supported. If I recall correctly, eap 6.1 supports Java 1.7 but not 1.8 (don't quote me on that, test it to be sure).

Comment: For that last statement I made: https://access.redhat.com/articles/111663.

Comment: @Shweta the reason you are getting this issue is that you are trying to use jdk1.8 with eap 6.1 and the explicit jars shipped with it do not run on java 8,please update your sts/eclipse and use at least eap 6.4+ if you are using jdk 1.8

Comment: Hi @SwetaPatra is this happening because of my adapter? As my server is JBOSS EAP 7.2. can you please provide me some links regarding this, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that this was happening because of my STS version. So I upgraded the STS and the issue is now resolved.