# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/spark/launcher/Main

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

learning Spark , trying to set up spark on my PC following instruction

I am using this build

> spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.6

I install `jdk-7u79-windows-x64.exe` and Disable IPv6 for Java applications

> setx /M _JAVA_OPTIONS "-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"

Install Python into `C:\Python27`

Put Hadoop binaries in  `C:\Hadoop`

> setx /M HADOOP_HOME C:\Hadoop
>
> setx /M path
>   "%path%;C:\Python27;%PROGRAMFILES%\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin;C:\Hadoop"

Then I need to run command to test  Spark interactive shell in Python by running the following

```
C:\Spark\bin\pyspark
```

However I am getting this error

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>C:\Spark\bin\pyspark
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/spark/launcher/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)

C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

here is java -version

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>java -version
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
java version "1.7.0_79"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)
```

I re-install JDK for a few times still no luck I am using win 10

I don not understand what I am missing, I check treds here but couldn't find any one which is working for me

Comment: Did you install and try with java 8?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unsupported major.minor version 52.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489398/unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0)

Comment: @ShankarKoirala yes it returns me that it needs Java7